# Знак & — происхождение

Tags: орфография, недопустимая-метка

Часто слово "and" и даже русское "и" заменяют значком &. А откуда вообще взялся этот знак и насколько он литературен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще не литературен! :-) Взялся из языков программирования.

Comment: Ответ неверен.

Comment: Согласен. В названиях фирм этот знак, пожалуй, нельзя считать нарушением нормы.

Answer (score 2):

Этот знак изначально использовался в коммерческой записи, где назывался "коммерческим AND". Аналогично @ - знак "коммерческого АТ".

Ещё пример использования - в названиях фирм типа "Jhones, Smith & Brown". Такой записи тоже уже несколько столетий.

Языки программирования, кстати, появились лет через триста после знака. Так что кто у кого взял - обсуждать не приходится.

Касательно литературности - не знаю, смотря что под этим иметь в виду.

//-----------------
**stopkran**
Я не gecube, но...

> Согласен. В названиях фирм этот знак, пожалуй, нельзя считать нарушением нормы.

Не будет слишком нагло поинтересоваться, с чем Вы не согласны?
Вам возражают прежде всего по части источника появления в языке. Что касается допустимости использования в названиях, то тут вообще нет единодушия, да и вопрос не слишком актуален.

> Думаю, неправильно предполагать, что в математике "иногда слово and заменяют на символ &" (или в программировании принято "иногда слово и заменять на символ &").

Вполне уместно. Во всяком случае у меня ни то ни другое явного протеста не вызвало. единственное, что можно бы уточнить, что математики скорее не "заменяют", но обозначают. Но с таким же успехом можно говорить, что в "обычной речи" (термин - Ваш) тоже "обозначают".

> Касательно литературности в данном контексте, думаю, можно говорить только об общих текстах.
> Туда, в общие тексты, конечно, попадает третий пункт. Это я проглядел.

Простите, что куда попадает? Пункт - в тексты? Или все-таки амперсанд?

Comment: В математике он тоже используется, в логике, один из знаков для логического умножения (то же "и"). Называется амперсанд. Но коммерческий, видимо, был раньше.

Comment: > Касательно литературности - не знаю, смотря что под этим иметь в виду.

В обычных предложениях его использование вместо "и" явно излишне.

Comment: Да в обычных предложениях его, вроде, и не используют.

Answer (score 1):

Этот знак ведет свою историю с римских времен, когда он, по сведениям [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4), был изобретен Марку Туллию Тирону, рабом Цицерона. Изначальное предназначение знака - сократить кол-во символов, что важно для скорописи. Таким образом, этому символу уже практически 20 столетий.

Касательно литературности - этот знак более характерен не для общих текстов, а для специализированных. Например, его можно встретить:

- в математике, как символ коньюнкции;
- в программирование, как операция;
- в названиях фирм, набранных латиницей, вместо "and".

[Альтернативное мнение от Лебедева](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/112/)

[статья от Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/type/topics/theampersand.html)

Comment: @gecube, вопрос был о замене от случая к случаю слов естественных языков на символ & (очевидно, в процессе речи). Думаю, неправильно предполагать, что в математике "иногда слово **and** заменяют на символ &" (или в программировании принято "иногда слово **и** заменять на символ &").

Касательно литературности в данном контексте, думаю, можно говорить _только_ об общих текстах. Туда, в общие тексты, конечно, попадает третий пункт. Это я проглядел.

Comment: @stopkran, в процессе речи Вы не будете менять слова на символ.Это очевидно. Во-первых, у символа есть собственное название - "эт". Во-вторых, трудоемкость замены весьма высокая. Сравните союз "и" или английский "энд"("and") и "эт". Т.е. получается & может только появиться на письме.

> Думаю, неправильно предполагать, что в математике "иногда слово and заменяют на символ &" (или в программировании принято "иногда слово и заменять на символ &")

Ну, в математике и программировании используется своя форма записи утверждений и формул. Так что там действительно получается не "иногда", а все врем

Comment: @gecube, разумеется, я говорил о предполагаемой замене символов в *письменной* речи. В математике и программировании обсуждаемый символ (мне ближе название "амперсанд") является **словом языка**, "термином". Там попросту недопустимы иные формы записи. 

Ну, хотя в программировании да, есть варианты :-); но опять же там оператор **and** в некоторых языках можно заменять на **&&** - двойной амперсанд, а у одиночного, насколько мне известно, замены в пределах одного языка не существует.

Comment: @gecube, не совсем понял: у Лебедева мнение - альтернативное чему? Мнению кого-то из участников? Мнению Правил русской орфографии?..

Comment: Оно просто альтернативное.